# Laravel checkbox old

Tags: php, laravel, request

уважаемые знатоки))

Есть страница edit (редактировать). На ней есть проклятый - checkbox )).

Я открываю страницу, "галочка" установлена. Снимаю "галочку", делаю специально ошибку в валидации и сохраняю. **Страница перезагружается, подтягиваются данные с old(если они есть) или с БД - смотрим "галочка" установлена, хотя я ее снял))**

С базы данных, приходит $shop_map_point_one->main = 1.
При снятии галочки, old('main') == ПУСТО, при установки old('main') == 1. Поэтому действует 2е правило, а там 1.

Заранее благодарен!!!

```
<input name="main" type="checkbox" value="1"
{{old('main') ? (old('main') === '1' ? 'checked' : '') : ($shop_map_point_one->main == 1 ? 'checked' : '') }}>
```

Comment: А не проще `{{ old('main', $shop_map_point_one->main) !=1?: 'checked' }}`

Comment: Добрый человек) Спасибки @Walfter      Скажите пжл как эта конструкция работает old('main', $shop_map_point_one->main)       И проблема остается проблемой))

Comment: @ДенисТюрин,  old('value', 'default value') - документация https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old

Comment: @ДенисТюрин, а попадают ли данные в old() ? Если попадают проверяйте условия: {{old('main') ? (old('main') === '1' ? 'checked' : '') : ($shop_map_point_one->main == 1 ? 'checked' : '') }}>

Comment: Если вы хотите что бы у вас в этом поле всегда что то было добавьте перед чекбоксом скрытое поле с таким же именем но с другим значением... Вы в реквесте проверяете наличие чекбокса `$request->has('checkbox_name')` так и тут, если вы сняли галочку то она просто не попадает в реквест и в олд соответственно

Comment: В дополнение к моему комментарию выше если у вас один шаблон редактирования и создания то лучше использовать вот так `{{ old('main', optional($shop_map_point_one)->main) !=1?: 'checked' }}` ну или на самый отвратный случай `{{ old('main', @$shop_map_point_one->main) !=1?: 'checked' }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Walfter
Получилось так:

```
<input type="hidden" name="main" value="0">
<input name="main" type="checkbox" value="1"
{{ old('main', $shop_map_point_one->main) !=1?: 'checked' }} >
```

Comment: Для галочек наверное лучше используйте 0 для хидена и 1 для чекбокса, так правильней будет при преобразовании к булеву

Comment: Ну и почитайте мой последний комментарий там про использование подобной конструкции сразу в нескольких шаблонах как в форме создания так и в форме обновления

Comment: совершенно верно!